# Primefaces Push: Error on deploy in JBoss 7.2

Tags: java, primefaces, jboss, atmosphere

I have some errors with my Prime Push / atmosphere configuration, but in general application works. PrimePUSH examples also work. I'm not sure what my errors mean and how to fix it.

On deploy I have error 'URI scheme is not "file"':

```
12:07:08,102 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation
12:07:08,103 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$BytecodeBasedAnnotationProcessor being used
12:07:08,106 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:366) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.AnnotationDetector.toFile(AnnotationDetector.java:420) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.AnnotationDetector.detect(AnnotationDetector.java:297) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.scanForAnnotation(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:147) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor.configure(DefaultAnnotationProcessor.java:133) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoConfigureService(AtmosphereFramework.java:2260) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:707) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:614) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:86) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.primefaces.push.PushServlet.init(PushServlet.java:43) [primefaces-4.0.jar:4.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4.jar:7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

12:07:08,111 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Auto detecting atmosphere handlers /WEB-INF/classes/
12:07:08,151 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/
12:07:08,174 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Installed WebSocketProtocol org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol 
12:07:08,178 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Found multiple containers, please specify which one to use: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport, org.atmosphere.container.TomcatCometSupport,  until you do, Atmosphere will use:class org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport
12:07:08,181 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor
12:07:08,181 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
12:07:08,182 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor
12:07:08,183 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
12:07:08,183 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support
12:07:08,184 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support
12:07:08,184 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support
12:07:08,185 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support
12:07:08,186 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol
12:07:08,186 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor
12:07:08,187 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection
12:07:08,187 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213)  org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor
12:07:08,187 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.
12:07:08,192 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper
12:07:08,193 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) No BroadcasterCache configured. Broadcasted message between client reconnection will be LOST. It is recommended to configure the org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache
12:07:08,193 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster
12:07:08,194 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100
12:07:08,194 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Shared ExecutorService supported: true
12:07:08,225 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited
12:07:08,225 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200
12:07:08,225 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory
12:07:08,225 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor
12:07:08,225 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) HttpSession supported: true
12:07:08,225 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation
12:07:08,226 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport running under container: JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final
12:07:08,227 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Atmosphere Framework 2.1.0 started.
12:07:08,227 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) 

    For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
    http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org

12:07:08,227 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) AtmosphereServlet with native support for Tomcat 6/7 and JBossWeb Installed.
12:07:08,228 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:07:08,230 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor  Track Message Size Interceptor using | with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:07:08,230 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 213) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor UUID Tracking Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
12:07:08,343 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "app.war" with deployment "app.war"
```

After application is deployed - I have first entries in page console after page load:

```
"NetworkError: 501 Not Implemented - http://localhost:8080/primepush/message/qla/robert?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.0.3-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&X-atmo-protocol=true"
robert...ol=true
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
push.j...s&v=4.0 (row 1)

GET http://localhost:8080/primepush/message/qla/robe...ache-Date=0&X-atmo-protocol=true&_=1392721774715
```

And later everything goes ok.

My configuration of Prime PUSH - web.xml:
    
        Push Servlet
        org.primefaces.push.PushServlet
       
            org.atmosphere.useWebSocket
            false

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

 <init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.resumeOnBroadcast</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 <async-supported>true</async-supported>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there some misconfiguration im my web.xml?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for reporting. The issue is https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/1473 and will be fixed in 2.1.1. You can try it now using 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.

Thanks!

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: Thanks for answer Jeanfrancois. I tried new snapshot, but result unfortunately the same: `10:32:45,605 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 174) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"
 at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:366) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
 at org.atmosphere.util.annotation.AnnotationDetector.toFile(AnnotationDetector.java:420) [atmosphere-runtime-native-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]`

Comment: Line aren't matching. Are you sure you have the latest?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. There is URISyntaxException catch, but File.class throws IllegalArgumentException in this case. I've updated issue #1473 with code which works for me.